# OneToMany unidirectional with composite pk on the Many side

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.0, hibernate-mapping

I have the following simple example:

```
@Entity
public class Profile {
 @Id
 private long id;

 @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY) 
 @JoinColumn(name="profileId", nullable = false)
 private List<Preference> preferences;
}

@Entity
@IdClass(PreferenceId.class)
public class Preference1 {
  @Id
  private long id;
  @Id
  @Column(insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable = false)
  private long profileId;   
}
```

Whenever I try to persist a profile, there are two insert statements:

> insert into Profile(id) values(?)  -- PERFECT
>
> insert into Preference(profileId, id) values (?, ?) -- Also PERFECT

And then

```
16:21:12,257 TRACE BasicBinder:83 - binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - 1
16:21:12,257 TRACE BasicBinder:83 - binding parameter [2] as [BIGINT] - 10
16:21:12,257 TRACE BasicBinder:83 - binding parameter [3] as [BIGINT] - 0
16:21:12,257 ERROR SqlExceptionHelper:144 - Invalid column index
```

Why there are three parameters instead of two?

Comment: Can you post the code of the class PreferenceId ? Perhaps it's not matching the fields you marked with @Id in your entity ...

Comment: Almost 10 years later I have this exact same problem with identical setup using Spring Boot 2.6.6 and JPA

Answer (score 0):

```
public class PreferenceId implements Serializable {
    private long id;
    private long profileId;
    public PreferenceId(){}

    public long getId(){return id;}
    public void setId(long id){this.id = id;}
    public long getProfileId() {return profileId;}
    public void setProfileId(long profileId) {this.profileId = profileId;}
    //hashCode, equals
}
```